# How do I limit access to a cloud storage bucket to one process at a time?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am fairly new to GCP.

I have some items in a cloud storage bucket.

I have written some python code to access this bucket and perform update operations.

I want to make sure that whenever the python code is triggered, it has exclusive access to the bucket so that I do not run into some sort of race condition.

For example, if I put the python code in a cloud function and trigger it, I want to make sure it completes before another trigger occurs.  Is this automatically handled or do I have to do something to prevent this?  If I have to add something like a semaphore, will subsequent triggers happen automatically after the the semaphore is released?

Comment: How about you create a queue in Cloud Tasks limited to one task at a time, and you'll do the bucket updates through tasks in this queue? This will ensure there are no concurrent updates, plus you can queue any number of tasks and they'll be dispatched automatically as soon as the previous finishes. Doing custom semaphores and whatnot sounds needlessly complicated...

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko thanks for the quick reply. What I am trying to do is actually a queuing mechanism.  Using Cloud Tasks would work for most of what I need. However, there are a couple of things that I have not figured out how to do with Cloud Tasks.
1) I want to be able to optionally have tasks that run at (or after) a specific time.
2) I want to have a timeout for the task so that if it does not complete in a specified time it gets killed and the next task is dispatched.

Comment: ad 1) there are cron jobs in AppEngine, which can execute Cloud Task. There is also  Cloud Scheduler in GCP, which is basically a managed cron, but I dont have experience with it. ad 2) afaik no such mechanism is present there, that's up to you to implement it.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko comment is right and answers your requirement. have a closer look to Cloud Task: you can set timeout, retry, delayed execution,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the info supplied has been helpful.  The best answer has been to use a max-concurrent-dispatches setting of 1 so that only one task is dispatched at a time.

Answer (score 1):

- Google [Cloud
  Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) is a
  fully managed cron jobs scheduling service available in GCP. It's
  basically the cron jobs which trigger at a given time. All you need
  to do is specify the frequency(The time when the job needs to be
  triggered) and the target(HTTP, Pub/Sub, App Engine HTTP) and you can
  specify the retry configuration like Max retry attempts, Max retry
  duration etc..
- [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) has a built-in cron service that allows you to write a simple cron.yaml containing the time at which you want the job to run and which endpoint it should hit. App Engine will ensure that the cron is executed at the time which you have specified. Here’s a sample cron.yaml that hits the /tasks/summary endpoint in AppEngine deployment every 24 hours.

```
  cron:
  - description: "daily summary job"
    url: /tasks/summary
    schedule: every 24 hours
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. Sorry.